# Angular 2 - not working with Webstorm 11.01 and Jade 4.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, template-engine, routerlink

I have been working through the Angular 2 guide example that can be found at this location: https://plnkr.co/edit/I4ArEQTniO7MJtfzpBWl?p=preview .

On my desktop this application works fine with the inline template code but as soon as I change to the templateUrl file I have a problem.  I have found that this is due to issues with the combination of WebStorm, Jade and Angular 2. See blogs at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19625 and https://github.com/donpark/html2jade/issues/102.

One problem is that the html2jade converter changes attributes to lower case. Below is an example where the Link of routerlink and the Link & Active of routerlinkactive have the first letters changed to lower case.  I can fix that by changing attribute names as required.

The problem I cannot fix is the WebStorm errors that show up as indicated in the blogs.   In my case the last routerlink line, the one for contacts, causes a syntax error.

I would like to continue to use both WebStorm and Jade.  Does anyone know of a work around or if other versions of either product fix these problems?

```
h1.title Angular Router  
 nav
   a(routerlink='/crisis-center', routerlinkactive='active') Crisis Center
   a(routerlink='/heroes', routerlinkactive='active') Heroes
   a(routerlink='/admin', routerlinkactive='active') Admin
   a(routerlink='/login', routerlinkactive='active') Login
   a([routerlink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]") Contact
 router-outlet
 router-outlet(name='popup')
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded WebStorm 2017.1 released March 17, 2017 and it appears that the errors I was getting with the JADE have gone away.  I still have to manually change lowercase letters in attributes to upper case but that should not be a big issue.